# os.Mkdir and os.MkdirAll permissions

Tags: linux, go

I'm trying to create a log file at the start of my program.

I need to check if a `/log` directory exists if it doesn't create the directory then move on to creating the log file.

Well I tried to use `os.Mkdir` (as well as `os.MkdirAll`), but no matter what value I put into the second parameter I get a locked out folder with no permissions. What value should this be in order to get a read / write for user folder? I thought it would be `0x700` but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use octal notation directly:

```
os.Mkdir("dirname", 0700)
```

### Permission Bits

Permission bits are historically given in Octal, so the literal value must be prefixed by a `0`.  Otherwise it will be interpreted as decimal and give confusing results.  This is consistent with the Linux command `chmod`.

```
+-----+---+--------------------------+
| rwx | 7 | Read, write and execute  |
| rw- | 6 | Read, write              |
| r-x | 5 | Read, and execute        |
| r-- | 4 | Read,                    |
| -wx | 3 | Write and execute        |
| -w- | 2 | Write                    |
| --x | 1 | Execute                  |
| --- | 0 | no permissions           |
+------------------------------------+

+------------+------+-------+
| Permission | Octal| Field |
+------------+------+-------+
| rwx------  | 0700 | User  |
| ---rwx---  | 0070 | Group |
| ------rwx  | 0007 | Other |
+------------+------+-------+
```

[A Unix Permission Primer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/395461)

### Common Permission Usages

**0755** Commonly used on web servers. The owner can read, write, execute. Everyone else can read and execute but not modify the file.

**0777** Everyone can read write and execute. On a web server, it is not advisable to use ‘777’ permission for your files and folders, as it allows anyone to add malicious code to your server.

**0644** Only the owner can read and write. Everyone else can only read. No one can execute the file.

**0655** Only the owner can read and write, but not execute the file. Everyone else can read and execute, but cannot modify the file.

[www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/](http://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/)

### Directory Permissions on Linux

When applying permissions to directories on Linux, the permission bits have different meanings than on regular files. ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252))

**Read bit** The user can read the file names contained in the directory.
**Write bit** The user can {add,rename,delete} files names IF the execute bit is set too.
**Execute bit** The user can enter the directory and access the files inside.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252

### Permissions Calculator

[image: permissions calculator]

A handy [permissions calculator](http://permissions-calculator.org/).

Comment: I don't understand how you obviously seem to understand unix permissions, given an explanation for them, yet still say that "in some cases, you will need to set the 777 permissions before you can upload any file to the server (For example, uploading images in WordPress)" NO! You NEVER need in except in very few cases (like `/tmp`, but that has the `sticky` bit set so it's not the same). If you need to upload things, then set the user of the directory to the user running the webserver or PHP. That's enough. No need to have random users or the MTA or whatever to be able to write to this dir

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks for the extra info. I copied the contents of this answer from several places. (see the source links.) Do you know of any blog posts or documentation that explains the ins and outs of using unix permissions?

Comment: I wrote a [brief introduction here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921) which should cover most of the basics (I'm working on a more expanded version)... In the Wordpress example, you'll want to set the upload directory to the user that needs to write to it (that is, the user running `php` or the webserver), and set it to `755`, so that *only* that user can write to it.

Comment: That looks pretty good. I've updated the the 777 permissions text above.

Comment: This answer turns a blind eye to the requirement of the extra `0` that precedes the permission values. Can someone speak to that and add it to the answer?

Comment: Also worth noting that directories need the *execute* permission. It's a weird Unix thing.

Comment: @Timmmm I've updated the post with some extra info. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: @Timmmm directory need execute permission so you can _cd_ into it.

Comment: @Shadoninja I edited the answer to give the reason for the `0` prefix.

Answer (score 26):

@Daniel's statement in his answer is not really correct, and also it talks about a decimal number and then uses an octal one, as @SashaCrofter correctly pointed out in his comment.

In reality, it doesn't matter what *form* your permission value is in as long as it represents sensible Unix permissions.

Since permission bits on POSIX file systems come in triples of bits — three bits for owner, group and others access, plus three bits of modifiers (such as sticky bits), — it's customary to use octal numbers to represent permissions as each *digit* in an octal number represents a three-bit value.

Hence, when you use 0700 in Go code, the leading 0 is stripped and is only there to tell the parser it sees an octal number literal, and the following three letters stand for the owner, group and others permissions, in this order.  Should you, say, want to also set the group sticky bit as well as making the file system object group-readable and executable, you'd specify 02750 and so on.

Note that the actual permissions the file system object acquires is further modulated by the active `umask` of the process which creates the object.

To get more grip on these topics, it's best to read the `chmod` manual pages and general literature on Unix-like operating systems.

Answer (score 22):

You can reset the umask to 0. I would call this as the first thing in my main file

```
syscall.Umask(0)
```

Example

```
_ = os.MkdirAll("/tmp/dirs/1", 0664)
syscall.Umask(0)
_ = os.MkdirAll("/tmp/dirs/2", 0664)
```

Result

```
/tmp/dirs$ stat -c '%A %a %n' *
drw-r--r-- 644 1
drw-rw-r-- 664 2
```

Comment: this is the real answer

Comment: Instead I think using `0744` is the best option.

Answer (score 13):

Besides the other answers, remember that on Unix and Linux style operating systems, all programs run with a *umask* setting.  The umask, which in many cases defaults to 022 or sometimes 002, is the set of permissions that the system will *automatically remove* from file and directory creation requests.

What this means is that most programs–there are several exceptions to this rule—should use mode `0666` for creating files and mode `0777` for creating directories.  The *user's configuration*, recorded in the running process, says which of these permissions to *take away*.  If the user's setting is `022`, and we create a file with mode `0666`, the actual setting we get is `rw-r--r--`: read and write for the user, read-only for the group, and read-only for others.

If a user wishes to extend writability to their group, they need only set their umask to `2`: now they take away write permission for others, but leave it for their group.  New files are now created with mode `rw-rw-r--`.  The *program* does not change: it still uses `0666` for its mode.  But the *files* are created with mode `0664`.

Similarly, if you call `os.Mkdir` or `os.MkdirAll` with `0777`, the umask will take away the unwanted permissions, leaving you with the right permissions.

But I mentioned that there are exceptions.  These include programs that make copies of sensitive information meant only for the user: these should generally use mode `0700` for directories and `0600` for files.  They *may* include long-running servers that act as a system user rather than any one individual ... although those servers *could* be run with a correct umask, in which case, `0777` or `0666` is fine.

You must apply some judgment here.  Programs that are especially security-conscious, such as ssh or similar, may wish to use limited permissions, and may even want to check (with `os.Lstat` or similar) that permissions are appropriately tight on important directories.

(Note that the umask *does not apply* to `os.Chmod` calls.  Here *you* choose the mode directly.)

Comment: Great explanation. If you could add some sources to this info where they write the ideas in such simple way as yours, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @Mike: I'm really not sure where to find *simple* descriptions. [The Wikipedia umask page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) has good information, though. I learned this stuff the hard way back in the early 1980s...

Answer (score 5):

One way to make sure that you're setting the kind of permissions you want, without figuring out the complex calculations in octal, is to use the very convenient `FileMode` constants in package `os`:

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode

I usually use `os.ModePerm` (which is actually coded as `0777`) for fully permissive directories, such as those required for caches or temporary files, but your mileage may vary. To set the additional bits (sticky, etc.), which, as @kostix has noted, has to deal with the issue of octal representation of flags in Go, you can always use something like:

```go
if err := os.MkdirAll("my/tmp/dir", os.ModeSticky|os.ModePerm); err != nil {
  ... handle error ...
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qb9pV_gSqVW)

As always, it's worth mentioning *again* that these permissions are 'filtered' by whatever `umask` has been set.

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham thanks so much for catching my stupid error! Heh! :-) The answer as it shows now is quite correct.