# How to create nested directories using Mkdir in Golang?

Tags: go, mkdir

I am trying to create a set of nested directories from a Go executable such as 'dir1/dir2/dir3'. I have succeeded in creating a single directory with this line:

```
os.Mkdir("." + string(filepath.Separator) + c.Args().First(),0777);
```

However, I have no idea how to approach creating a predetermined nested set of directories inside of that directory.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

`os.Mkdir` is used to create a single directory. To create a folder path, instead try using:

```
os.MkdirAll(folderPath, os.ModePerm)
```

[Go documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#MkdirAll)

> func MkdirAll(path string, perm FileMode) error
>
> MkdirAll creates a directory named path, along with any necessary parents, and returns nil, or else returns an error. The permission bits perm are used for all directories that MkdirAll creates. If path is already a directory, MkdirAll does nothing and returns nil.

**Edit:**

Updated to correctly use `os.ModePerm` instead.
For concatenation of file paths, use package `path/filepath` as described in @Chris' answer.

Comment: You may want to choose between `0755` and `os.ModePerm`.

Answer (score 128):

This way you don't have to use any magic numbers:

```
os.MkdirAll(newPath, os.ModePerm)
```

Also, rather than using + to create paths, you can use:

```
import "path/filepath"
path := filepath.Join(someRootPath, someSubPath)
```

The above uses the correct separators automatically on each platform for you.

Answer (score 10):

This is one alternative for achieving the same but it avoids race condition caused by having two distinct "check ..and.. create" operations.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main()  {
    if err := ensureDir("/test-dir"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Directory creation failed with error: " + err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Proceed forward
}

func ensureDir(dirName string) error {

    err := os.MkdirAll(dirName, os.ModeDir)

    if err == nil || os.IsExist(err) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: `MkdirAll`: "If path is already a directory, MkdirAll does nothing and returns nil.", so there's no need to check `IsExist` error

Answer (score 9):

If the issue is to create all the necessary parent directories, you could consider using [`os.MkDirAll()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#MkdirAll)

> `MkdirAll` creates a directory named path, along with any necessary parents, and returns nil, or else returns an error.

The [path_test.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f3b73e040c24c5a589373e431b91babc249640bc/src/os/path_test.go#L18-L25) is a good illustration on how to use it:

```
func TestMkdirAll(t *testing.T) {
    tmpDir := TempDir()
    path := tmpDir + "/_TestMkdirAll_/dir/./dir2"
    err := MkdirAll(path, 0777)
    if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("MkdirAll %q: %s", path, err)
    }
    defer RemoveAll(tmpDir + "/_TestMkdirAll_")
...
}
```

(Make sure to specify a sensible permission value, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921772/6309))

Answer (score 8):

An utility method like the following can be used to solve this.

```
import (
  "os"
  "path/filepath"
  "log"
)

func ensureDir(fileName string) {
  dirName := filepath.Dir(fileName)
  if _, serr := os.Stat(dirName); serr != nil {
    merr := os.MkdirAll(dirName, os.ModePerm)
    if merr != nil {
        panic(merr)
    }
  }
}



func main() {
  _, cerr := os.Create("a/b/c/d.txt")
  if cerr != nil {
    log.Fatal("error creating a/b/c", cerr)
  }
  log.Println("created file in a sub-directory.")
}
```