# mkdir if not exists using golang

Tags: go, directory, path, filepath, mkdir

I am learning golang(beginner) and I have been searching on both google and stackoverflow but I could not find an answer so excuse me if already asked, but how can I mkdir if not exists in golang.

For example in node I would use fs-extra with the function [ensureDirSync](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#ensuredirdir-callback) (if blocking is of no concern of course)

```
fs.ensureDir("./public");
```

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I've ran across two ways:

1. Check for the directory's existence and create it if it doesn't exist:

   ```
   if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
       err := os.Mkdir(path, mode)
       // TODO: handle error
   }
   ```

However, this is susceptible to a race condition: the path may be created by someone else between the `os.Stat` call and the `os.Mkdir` call.

2. Attempt to create the directory and ignore any issues (ignoring the error is not recommended):

   ```
   _ = os.Mkdir(path, mode)
   ```

Comment: For anyone wondering what the variable `mode` is, see: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode.

You probably want to use `os.ModeDir` as its value.

Comment: Also for those wondering about the `mode`, you could use `os.Mkdir("dirname", 0700)` if you want to be able to write into that directory from the same program, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249467/os-mkdir-and-os-mkdirall-permission-value/31151508) for more details.

Comment: Why do we ignore any issues when we do os.Mkdir() ?

Comment: @Giannis It will error if it already exists, which is okay. Probably not recommended though.

Comment: When creating a directory to store files in the mode `os.ModeDir`. The new directory does not have enough permissions. I found only `os.ModePerm` worked for me. Which is equivalent to `0777` or `drwxr-xr-x`. I think the permissions can be a bit lower but `0666` did not do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't option 1 be susceptible to a race condition if someone else creates the directory in between you checking if exists and then creating it?

Comment: @Giannis, @472084: There are other reasons `os.Mkdir()` can return a non-nil error too. So the error should absolutely be checked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932672/3309046 is arguably a better answer that doesn't have the issues in this answer.

Comment: With the caveat that it creates parent directories even if that's not intended. The question specifically asks for `mkdir` not `mkdir -p`. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 245):

Okay I figured it out thanks to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34451620/11926)

```
import(
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

newpath := filepath.Join(".", "public")
err := os.MkdirAll(newpath, os.ModePerm)
// TODO: handle error
```

Relevant Go doc for MkdirAll:

> **MkdirAll** creates a directory named path,
> along with any necessary parents, and returns nil,
> or else returns an error.
>
> ...
>
> **If path is already a directory, MkdirAll does nothing
> and returns nil.**

Comment: This is the best answer, and is using the stdlib. This is especially useful when used alongside os.Create, where you  might need to create sub-dirs as well (using `filepath.Dir("path/to/file")` on the complete path to the file is a nice approach in my eyes.

Comment: You might want to check for any error response on the MkdirAll call like:
`
if err := os.MkdirAll("/somepath/", os.ModeDir); err != nil {
     fmt.Println("Cannot create hidden directory.")
}
`

Answer (score 9):

This is one alternative for achieving the same but it avoids race condition caused by having two distinct "check ..and.. create" operations.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main()  {
    if err := ensureDir("/test-dir"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Directory creation failed with error: " + err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Proceed forward
}

func ensureDir(dirName string) error {
    err := os.Mkdir(dirName, os.ModeDir)
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if os.IsExist(err) {
        // check that the existing path is a directory
        info, err := os.Stat(dirName)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !info.IsDir() {
            return errors.New("path exists but is not a directory")
        }
        return nil
    }
    return err  
}
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. The `os.IsExist(err)` check in `ensureDir` is not sufficient: the existing path may not necessarily be a directory. So `ensureDir` will return a nil error but ultimately the item at the path may not be a directory (it may be a reguar file, for instance).

Comment: I've addressed the issue described in my earlier comment in an edit to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

So what I have found to work for me is:

```
import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
)

//Get the cur file dir
path, err := filepath.Abs("./") // current opened dir (NOT runner dir)

// If you want runner/executable/binary file dir use `_, callerFile, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
// path := filepath.Dir(callerFile)`
if err != nil {
    log.Println("error msg", err)
}

//Create output path
outPath := filepath.Join(path, "output")

//Create dir output using above code
if _, err = os.Stat(outPath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    var dirMod uint64
    if dirMod, err = strconv.ParseUint("0775", 8, 32); err == nil {
        err = os.Mkdir(outPath, os.FileMode(dirMod))
    }
}
if err != nil && !os.IsExist(err)  {
    log.Println("error msg", err)
}
```

I like the portability of this.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could attempt creating the file and check that the error returned isn't a "file exists" error

```
if err := os.Mkdir(path, mode); err != nil && !os.IsExist(err) {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. Particularly the `!os.IsExist(err)` check is incorrect. The existing path may not necessarily be a directory. So ultimately the code will continue onward (i.e. `log.Fatal` won't be executed), but `path` may not be a directory (it may be a reguar file, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

To create a directory if it does not exist, you can follow these steps:

Import the "os" package at the beginning of your Go program.
Use the "os.Mkdir()" function to create the directory.

```html
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Specify the path of the directory you want to create
    directoryPath := "./my_directory"

    // Check if the directory already exists
    if _, err := os.Stat(directoryPath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // The directory does not exist, so create it using os.MkdirAll()
        err := os.MkdirAll(directoryPath, 0755) // 0755 sets the permissions for the directory
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error creating directory:", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("Directory created successfully.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Directory already exists.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for making new directory in golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Specify the directory path you want to create
    dirPath := "my_directory"

    // Create the directory with the specified path
    err := os.Mkdir(dirPath, 0755) // 0755 sets permissions for the directory
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Directory created:", dirPath)
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you