# How to make a directory in Golang?

Tags: go

So I'm attempting to create a CMS where each user makes their own website and it is stored in a directory named as their choosing. However when I use

```
os.Mkdir("/Users/anonrose/Documents/goCode/src/github.com/anonrose/GoDataStructs/tests/myWebsite", os."some permission")
```

the "some permission" part is what I'm having troubles with. When I attempt to access the directory once it's been created I never have the correct permission. Is there a `os.FileMode` that I can use to set the permissions as read and write for anyone when I go to create the directory.

Comment: Have you tried `os.Mkdir("/Users/anonrose/Documents/goCode/src/github.com/anonrose/GoDataStructs/tests/myWebsite", int(0777))`?

Comment: Note the leading 0 in `0777` to make the value octal, just `777` will give strange permissions.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that didn't but I just used `os.ModePerm` which is of type FileMode so that got it done. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a duplicated question of [os.MkDir and os.MkDirAll permission value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249467/os-mkdir-and-os-mkdirall-permission-value)

Answer (score 11):

If you need to set explicit permission bits not listed [here](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) then use `os.FileMode`

```
os.Mkdir("/path/to/dir", os.FileMode(0522))
```

The least significant 9 bits of the uint32 represent the file permissions, so 0777 would be 511 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [os.ModeDir](//golang.org/pkg/os#ModeDir):

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   os.Mkdir("March", os.ModeDir)
}
```